# ORM - Django query grouping and joining itself

Tags: python, django, join, orm, django-queryset

I'm developing a program do track people that you have already played with on dota2, but I have no wonder on how to translate this sql query to a django query.

The models are:

```
class Match(models.Model):
    ...

class Account(models.Model):
    ...

class MatchPlayer(models.Model):
    match = models.ForeignKey(Match)
    player_account = models.ForeignKey(Account)
    ...
```

and the query I want to translate is something like:

```
SELECT count(*), dmp1.player_account_id, dmp2.player_account_id 
FROM matchplayer dmp1
JOIN  matchplayer dmp2 on dmp1.match_id = dmp2.match_id
WHERE dmp1.player_account_id=<some account id>
GROUP BY 2, 3
ORDER BY 1 desc
```

Is it possible to translate it to a django query or I have to use it as SQL?

Comment: I believe it is possible, but I don't have an example handy.  Look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#extra and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#id7 

Keeping in mind that you can chain filters and that queries are not evaluated until you actually go to use the data.

Comment: I'm curious, how will you populate that DB?

Comment: There is a rest api where you can get some data of matches. [dota2dev forum](http://dev.dota2.com/forumdisplay.php?f=411) has some documentation

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to know the players that has played against player with pk=1:

```
queryset = Account.objects.filter(matchplayer__match__in=[m.pk for m in Match.objects.filter(matchplayer__player_account=1)]).exclude(pk=1).annotate(count=Count('matchplayer__match'))
```

You'll get a queryset of all matching players, each object containing a new attribute 'count' corresponding to the number of times that specific player has played against our target player pk=1. So, you can do something like (assuming the Account object has a 'name' field):

```
[(p.name, p.count) for p in queryset]
```

Comment: I tried what you sad, but it throws "Exception Value: too many SQL variables", since your query reaches the database twice, your lambda expression will turn into parameter, and there are some players with more than 3k games.